# How to open app location settings in swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

I can open app settings with `UIAplication.shared.open(URL(string: "app-settings:")!)`, but how can I open exactly app location settings? For example Settings -> MyApp -> Location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can only open the app setting rather than open options inside the setting. I've checked applications like Instagram, Google Map they all redirect to app setting but not to location option.